# Formatting python output for tex math mode?

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have a python script that outputs `x0+x1*x2+y40+y1` (variables with subscripts and arithmetic operators).

Now I want to add this output to a `tex` file in math mode. So, for this case, I need the formatted output would be:

> $x_{0}+x_{1}\ast x_{2}+y_{40}+y_{1}$

(The expression is enclosed by two `$`'s, each number is enclosed by `_{` and `}`, `*` is replaced by `\ast`).

What is the best way to do this?

I could not solve it even now. Problem is that the subscripts numbers are of arbitrary lengths.

This is my naive and unsuccessful try:

```
expr = 'x0+x1*x2+y40+y1'
expr = expr.replace('*', '\\ast ')
expr = expr.replace('x', 'x_')
expr = expr.replace('y', 'y_')

#import re

#for s in expr:
#   if re.match(r'\D', s):
#       print s,

expr = '$'+expr+'$'
print expr
```

Comment: You might want to try https://github.com/JelteF/PyLaTeX (in particular the `math = Subsection('Math that is incorrect', data=[Math(data=['2*3', '=', 9])])` line might be something to base your code off of if you decide to use this library). Disclaimer: I have never used this myself, just found it right now with a quick google search.

Comment: This hardly calls for regular expressions. You can probably get by with `string.replace()`.  That being said - have you tried anything? Will you please show us?

Comment: If you want to do this yourself, I would suggest that you try to obtain the _expression tree_ and then define rules for how the expression is written to a \LaTeX file. For example, the expression x1*x2 would contain at the root level a multiplication operator, and as leaves x1 and x2. So then the rule for the multiplication operator would be to print \, instead of the * symbol. As for x1 and x2, you can do string operations to find the numerical component and put it knot a subscript. I don't know if there's an existing library in Python that could be used to obtain the expression tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `re.sub` method to substitute every occurrence of a number with `_{N}`, and use str.replace for everything else. The pattern `\d+` will match one or more subsequent digits.

```
import re

def texify(text):
    text = re.sub('\d+', lambda match: '_{' + match.group(0) + '}', text)
    return '$' + text.replace('*', '\\ast ') + '$'

print texify('x0+x1*x2+y40+y1')
```

However, note that this is a fairly brittle solution -- for example, it'll fail if you have any numbers that are not meant to be subscripts.

Comment: You may like to modify: `text` in the first line inside `textify` (in pace of `a`) and `\\ast` in place of `\ast`. :-) Anyway, thanks. As my current outputs do not contain any co-efficients, it'll work fine.

Comment: @pushpen.paul -- whoops! Thanks for catching those typos :)